# Sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+1}{3^k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+1}{3^k}$$

Steps:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{3^k} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^k}$$

$$Sn = \frac {a1(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$

$$r = \frac{second term}{first term}$$
$$a1 = \frac {1}{3^0}$$
$$a2 = \frac {1}{3} + \frac {1}{3^1}$$

$a1 = 0+1 = 1$
a2 = $\frac{2}{3}$

r = 2/3

$$S∞ = \frac {a1(1-r^∞)}{1-r}$$
$$S∞ = \frac {1(1- (2/3)^∞)}{1-(2/3)}$$
$$S∞ = \frac {1(1- 0)}{1-(2/3)}$$
$$S∞ = \frac {1}{1/3}$$
$$S∞ = 3$$

Here I get the sum being equal to three when in fact it is apparently 9/4. I am finding very limited information on how to solve infinite sum of series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)x^k=\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^nx^{k+1}\biggr)'=\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x^{k}\biggr)'.$$

*Some details*:

As a result,$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)x^k=\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k}\biggr)'.$$
Now it is well-known that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k}=\frac x{1-x}=-1+\frac1{1-x}, \enspace\text{so }\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)x^k=\\frac1{(1-x)^2}.$$

Comment: what is x here?

Comment: Any number. For instance $\frac13$… ;o)

Comment: Can you really use any number? If I wanted to use $$\frac {45}{6}$$ would I still get the right answer?

Comment: As far as it is a finite sum, yes. If you have to go to infinity, it requires $|x|<1$. B.t.w., I've modified the hint, since you've changed the initial value of $k$.

Comment: So if it is an infinite sum, x can be any number greater than 0 and less than 1.  Does your steps to solving an infinite sum of series hold true for solving any infinite sum of series? I can use those steps for finding any sum of finite or infinite series? Also, why does k = 0 increase to k=1 in the last part of that equation.

Comment: The  property I used is that the sum of a (convergent) power series can be differentiated term by term (it also can be integrated), with the same radius of convergence

Comment: Using your answer I am now getting 1 for the sum of series. $$\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x^{k}\biggr)'.$$ taking the derivative of $x^k$ is = $k(x)^0$ this is equal to 1 when k=1.

Comment: You first must use the formula for the sum of the geometric series.

Comment: Ok my original question shows that is equal to 3.

Comment: I have now tried $S = \frac{a1}{1-r}$ where r = the common ratio between a2/a1, and again I am getting the sum = 3.

Comment: With the way I point to, you should find $9/4$.

Comment: Using any portion of that equation will yield the same result, as all parts are equal to eachother. I will use $$\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)x^k$$ , this results in $$\sum_{k=0}^n(0+1)(1/3)^0$$ = 1(1) = 1. Additionally I am unsure of how to take a derivative of a sum of series.

Comment: Which exponent is respective of the entire term? Is it 1 or k? k is the exponent of the term x. It would make sense that 1 is the term of everything in brackets then. However, if that is the case then 1-1 = 0, making the exponent of the sum of series 0 and thus = 1. This would mean that the derivative of the sum of series if the third part of the equation is also 1.

Comment: No in you last but one comment, you did not calculate the sum of the series: $k$ has to  be increased by $1$ at each step. Also, to differentatiate the sum of the series, you simply have to differentiate its closed form.

Comment: And how do you find the closed form of an infinite sum of series?

Comment: It's the geometric  series! And it's not an infinite sum of series, it's the series which is an infinite sum (of powers of $x$ in the present case).

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Geometric series with infinite sum.  I have found the first four terms (I am unsure of how many terms I need to evaluate). The first four terms are: 1, 2/3, 1/3, and 4/27. I did this because you said in your comment you need to increase k by 1 at each step to calculate the sum of series. However I think it would be impossible to do this infinitely many times. This is where I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: The common ratio here is not the same between each set of successive terms. For example between the first two terms it is 2/3, and between the next set term a3 and a2 it is 2.

Comment: Actually the ratio between term three and term 2 is 1/2, but that does not detract from my point. In order for this to be a geometric series the common ratio MUST be the same for every successive term. Here this is not the case.

Comment: It is the *derivative* of the geometric series, it's not the geometric series itself.

Comment: Yes I have now solved this problem for myself. What I needed to do to visualize this problem was separate it into power series and geometric series: sum of k/3^k  + sum of 1/3^k.

Comment: That's a more complicated way, in my opinion.

Comment: I've added details for the general formula.

Comment: It appears quite similar to what I did, the geometric series sum is quite simple. You differentiated, after that  substitute in $$\frac {1}{3}$$ for x.  You say it is simpler to do it this way, why?  I also see why you cannot take k=0 of derivative of the sum of series, and instead k=1.

Comment: The's no $k=0$ in the r.h.s.  because i won't appear anyway! For you your way, how do you manage $\sum\frac k{3^k}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+1}{3^k}
&=\frac{3}{2}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{3}\bigg)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+1}{3^k}\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{k+1}{3^k}-\frac{k+1}{3^{k+1}}\bigg)\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{3^0}-\frac{1}{3^1}+\frac{2}{3^1}-\frac{2}{3^{2}}+\frac{3}{3^2}-\frac{3}{3^3}+\frac{4}{3^3}-\frac{4}{3^4}+...\bigg)\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{3^0}+\frac{1}{3^1}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{3^4}+...\bigg)\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}\bigg)\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{2} \\
&=\frac{9}{4} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+series+from+k%3D0+to+infinity+((k%2B1)%2F(3%5Ek))

Comment: It is 9/4 not 5/4

Comment: @sawreals, u put $k=0$ instead of $k=1$

Comment: It is from k=0 to infinity. I made a mistake

Comment: But can you also explain your steps? Where do you get 3/2 and (1-(1/3)) from in your first step?

Comment: @sawreals2 I added those two numbers because $$\frac{3}{2}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{3}\bigg)=1$$
and because the $1-1/3$ causes the series to telescope into a geometric series, which you should know how to evaluate.

Comment: is this a specific rule where we are required to make two values equal to 1? How did you know to use 3/2 , 1, and -1/3 ? You could have also used (4/3)(1-(1/4). Also you proceed to introduce exponent k+1 in your next step, why?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

In general,
$$
S(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}, \quad \forall |x| < 1.
$$
Therefore,
$$
S'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k
      = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}x^k
      = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k x^{k-1}
      = \frac{1}{x} \sum_{k=1}^\infty k x^k
$$
but transforming the other side,
$$
S'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = xS'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k x^k, \quad \forall |x| <1.
$$